# Calling scheme function from Java using kawa, but half the returned list is omitted and replaced by three dots (...)

Tags: scheme, kawa

I wrote the following scheme function, which works as expected when called in Dr Racket, but only returns half of the result when called using kawa.

```
(define getYValues (lambda (f base lst)
              (if (null? lst) 
              base
              (cons (f (car lst)) (getYValues f base (cdr lst)))
              )
      )
)
```

The values used for testing are:

```
(getYValues 
(lambda (x)
    (* x x)
    )
 '() 
'(-5.0 -4.5 -4.0 -3.5 -3.0 -2.5 -2.0 -1.5 -1.0 -0.5 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 ))
```

In Dr Racket it returns the correct result:
(25.0 20.25 16.0 12.25 9.0 6.25 4.0 2.25 1.0 0.25 0.0 0.25 1.0 2.25 4.0 6.25 9.0 12.25 16.0 20.25)

But called from our Java application using kawa it returns:
(25.0 20.25 16.0 12.25 9.0 6.25 4.0 2.25 1.0 0.25 ...)

Does anyone know why the list is cut off and half of it replaced by ...?

I use Scheme.eval to call the function

## Update/solution

The following code solved my problem:

```
LList list = new LList();
try {
    list = (LList)scm.eval(schemeCall);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
double[] yValues = new double[LList.length(list)];
for (int i = 0; i<yValues.length;i++) {
    yValues[i] = ((DFloNum) list.get(i)).doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just call `map`? It does the same thing as your function.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to scheme, so I wasn't aware of map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess: it's possible that the list is complete, but only a part of it is displayed, for presentation purposes - the rest is assumed to be in the `...` part. To check, print the `length` of the list, it must be correct even if not all the elements are shown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Scheme.eval returns an Object, which I cast to a string after which I extract the numbers using regex. Is there a way to get a list from the return value so I can get the length of it?

Comment: @Videre: It will be list (in the sense of Kawa/Scheme) already. Try `(length input)` and `(length output)`.

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same thing. I figured it out, take a look at my updated question if you're interested.